# Detect if a page has a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I just want some simple JQ/JS to check if the current page/window (not a particular element) has a vertical scrollbar.

Googling gives me stuff that seems overly complex for just this basic feature.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 104):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if body height is higher than window height :)
    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
    }

    // Check if body width is higher than window width :)
    if ($("body").width() > $(window).width()) {
        alert("Horizontal Scrollbar! D:<");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 but for the sake of exactness, this only checks whether the content expands further than the viewport. If the `overflow` property of the `body` is set to `hidden` somewhere along the line, it won't work. Setting hidden on a body is extremely rare, though.

Comment: This does not work if the body height matches the window height, which is the case if the doc height matches the viewport exactly *then a horizontal scrollbar is added*.  It will force vert. scrollbar but doc/body/window height are the same; it will NOT alert "vertical scrollbar" even tho there is one.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that I had to use `$(document)` instead of `$("body")`, this worked for me when body didn't (I have an absolute positoned container with an aspect ratio on width/height)

Comment: I have report page on Chrome browser where it initially displays a scroll bar and vanishes in a matter of milliseconds which looks like a browser behaviour since I did not programme it. So this function return true always in my case..

Comment: @TiuTalk for me $("body").height() & $(window).height() gives same value, instead I use $(document).height() > $(window).height() it works for me.

Answer (score 90):

try this:

```
var hasVScroll = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
```

This will only tell you if the vertical scrollHeight is bigger than the height of the viewable content, however.  The `hasVScroll` variable will contain true or false.

If you need to do a more thorough check, add the following to the code above:

```
// Get the computed style of the body element
var cStyle = document.body.currentStyle||window.getComputedStyle(document.body, "");

// Check the overflow and overflowY properties for "auto" and "visible" values
hasVScroll = cStyle.overflow == "visible" 
             || cStyle.overflowY == "visible"
             || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflow == "auto")
             || (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflowY == "auto");
```

Comment: +1 Nice! And with the necessary computed style (which was the point at which I decided not to get involved with this question ;)

Comment: lol yeah I was debating whether or not to make the extra effort to write it because in many cases it's not needed.

Comment: Yeah, but it's the only really proper way. Good job!

Comment: I found a page layout where this technique does not work.  For some odd reason, document.body is smaller than the window, but document.documentElement is not so the code in this test says no vscrollbar, but there is one.

Comment: It didn't work for me in the internet explorer, while the one of TiuTalk does.

Comment: Are you missing a var keyword before hasVScroll or is that intentionally global?  I see it's checking the value of hasVScroll in the condition, before it's assigned, so it seems like it's maintaining state from a previous check.

Comment: This results in hasVScroll being true whenever overflowY is 'visible' regardless of whether the scrollHeight is greater than the clientHeight. Maybe you meant `cStyle.overflow === 'scroll'`?

Comment: The above code does not work. Browser: Chrome 56. Url: https://news.greylock.com/the-hierarchy-of-engagement-expanded-648329d60804#.w3zl8fs6p

Comment: @BT `cStyle.overflow == "visible" ` can show scroll bars when the element is the `document.body`. But it should  be (hasVScroll && cStyle.overflow == "visible" && element.nodeName == "BODY") . Plus it needs to check for `cStyle.overflow === 'scroll'` as you point out.

Answer (score 48):

I tried the previous answer and doesn't seem to be working the $("body").height() does not necessarily represent the whole html height.

I have corrected the solution as follows:

```
// Check if body height is higher than window height :) 
if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) { 
    alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:"); 
} 

// Check if body width is higher than window width :) 
if ($(document).width() > $(window).width()) { 
    alert("Horizontal Scrollbar! D:<"); 
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
let hasScrollbar = window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Comment: This did the job, Thanks.

Comment: Yes this works ...

Comment: should be the accepted answer, 2024 and this the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 18):

Let's bring this question back from the dead ;) There is a reason Google doesn't give you a simple solution. Special cases and browser quirks affect the calculation, and it is not as trivial as it seems to be.

Unfortunately, there are problems with the solutions outlined here so far. I don't mean to disparage them at all - they are great starting points and touch on all the key properties needed for a more robust approach. But I wouldn't recommend copying and pasting the code from any of the other answers because

- they don't capture the effect of positioned content in a way that is reliable cross-browser. The answers which are based on body size miss this entirely (the body is not the offset parent of such content unless it is positioned itself). And those answers checking `$( document ).width()` and `.height()` fall prey to [jQuery's buggy detection of document size](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#what-does-it-do-that-jquery-doesnt).
- Relying on `window.innerWidth`, if the browser supports it, makes your code fail to detect scroll bars in mobile browsers, where the width of the scroll bar is generally 0. They are just shown temporarily as an overlay and don't take up space in the document. Zooming on mobile also becomes a problem that way (long story).
- The detection can be thrown off when people explicitly set the overflow of both the `html` and `body` element to non-default values (what happens then is a little involved - see [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434416/overflowhidden-on-body-is-broken-in-ios6/28673415#28673415)).
- In most answers, body padding, borders or margins are not detected and distort the results.

I have spent more time than I would have imagined on a finding a solution that "just works" (cough). The algorithm I have come up with is now part of a plugin, [jQuery.isInView](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview), which exposes [a `.hasScrollbar` method](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview#hasscrollbar-axis-). Have a look [at the source](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview/blob/6887aa7affd07877ee6d2c04d48d393c8092632d/src/jquery.isinview.js#L573-646) if you wish.

In a scenario where you are in full control of the page and don't have to deal with unknown CSS, using a plugin may be overkill - after all, you know which edge cases apply, and which don't. However, if you need reliable results in an unknown environment, then I don't think the solutions outlined here will be enough. You are better off using a well-tested plugin - mine or anybody elses.

Comment: Thanks. Quite a bit complicated! If you don't want to/need to be backward compatible is there perhaps an easier solution for html5 browsers? I mean perhaps the browser coders/w3c have been nice enough to just tell us if there are scrollbars or not on an element? ;-)

Comment: @Leo Not that I am aware of. Well, there is a [`window.scrollbars` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollbars) which has a single property, `visible`. Sounds promising but isn't. It is not supported in IE, including IE11. And it just tells you that there is _a_ scroll bar - but not which one. See the [test page here](http://jsbin.com/bofofo).

Comment: Thanks @hashchange. It sounds incredible stupid that it just tells if there is any scrollbar so I guess it is just some kind of test yet. A bit promising though. ;-)

Comment: Would you mind commenting on Andy E's answer? It seems like that one doesn't fall prey to any of the 4 points you brought up, but it sounds like you've done a ton more work on this than anyone else, so I'm curious where it would go wrong.

Comment: @BT Maybe I'm a bit dense this morning, but how do you get that code to detect that there is _no_ scrollbar? With default overflow settings, it always evaluates to true.

Comment: @hashchange Here's the function I derived from Andy E's answer that I'm using: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXpBVb

Comment: @BT Ok, great. Now let me lead you to the entrance of the rabbit hole ;) Here's [a demo](http://jsbin.com/tayurek/2/edit?html,js,output) where the content is not enough to fill the window. Your detection works in FF but fails in Chrome. And here's [another demo](http://jsbin.com/hoviri/2/edit?html,css,js,output) where a positioned element is placed far down the page. Your detection works in Chrome but fails in FF.

Comment: @BT  And I guess we can get into a bunch of weird failure modes when we begin to play with overflow settings because their [behaviour is a little odd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434416/overflowhidden-on-body-is-broken-in-ios6/28673415#28673415), but I've stopped right there.

Comment: Alright then fair enough. I suppose I've only used my function on things that aren't the document body. I see your function is hard coded for the window. This is some complicated junk that should just be a native built in function

Comment: I see that your code has written a couple things that I've written as dom utilties, including finding scrollbar width and css finding. I'm planning on creating a dom utility module (on github and npm) to put some of this difficult-to-write code, and I'm wondering if you'd want to help me do that.

Comment: @BT Sounds like an interesting idea. But doesn't a library of that sort, of decent quality, already exist? Anyway, I'm not in because I'm running 10 open source projects already, and I'm struggling to keep up. But if you'd like to share a link, I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: If it did, wouldn't we both be using it? Or wouldn't it have appeared on this SO question? I'll add a link here when I get around to putting it up.

Answer (score 16):

This one did works for me:

```
function hasVerticalScroll(node){
    if(node == undefined){
        if(window.innerHeight){
            return document.body.offsetHeight> window.innerHeight;
        }
        else {
            return  document.documentElement.scrollHeight > 
                document.documentElement.offsetHeight ||
                document.body.scrollHeight>document.body.offsetHeight;
        }
    }
    else {
        return node.scrollHeight> node.offsetHeight;
    }
}
```

For the body, just use `hasVerticalScroll()`.

Comment: This is the only answer in this thread that works on my Chrome

Comment: `clientHeight` is preferable over `offsetHeight` here. Otherwise you can have a thick border, and return there is no scrollbar when there is.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly none of these solutions tell you if a page has a vertical scrollbar.

`window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth` will give you the width of the scrollbar. This should work in anything IE9+ (not tested in the lesser browsers). (Or to strictly answer the question, `!!(window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth)`

Why? Let's say you have a page where the content is taller than the window height and the user can scroll up/down. If you're using Chrome on a Mac with no mouse plugged in, the user will not see a scrollbar. Plug a mouse in and a scrollbar will appear. (Note this behaviour can be overridden, but that's the default AFAIK).

Comment: The explanation of Chrome-Mouse behaviour helped me figure out what I thought was inconsistent behaviour. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    <script>
    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var hasVerticalScrollbar = scrollHeight > clientHeight;

    alert(scrollHeight + " and " + clientHeight); //for checking / debugging.
    alert("hasVerticalScrollbar is " + hasVerticalScrollbar + "."); //for checking / debugging.
    </script>
```

This one will tell you if you have a scrollbar or not. I've included some information that may help with debugging, which will display as a JavaScript alert.

Put this in a script tag, after the closing body tag.

Answer (score 2):

I found vanila solution

```js
var hasScrollbar = function() {
  // The Modern solution
  if (typeof window.innerWidth === 'number')
    return window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth

  // rootElem for quirksmode
  var rootElem = document.documentElement || document.body

  // Check overflow style property on body for fauxscrollbars
  var overflowStyle

  if (typeof rootElem.currentStyle !== 'undefined')
    overflowStyle = rootElem.currentStyle.overflow

  overflowStyle = overflowStyle || window.getComputedStyle(rootElem, '').overflow

    // Also need to check the Y axis overflow
  var overflowYStyle

  if (typeof rootElem.currentStyle !== 'undefined')
    overflowYStyle = rootElem.currentStyle.overflowY

  overflowYStyle = overflowYStyle || window.getComputedStyle(rootElem, '').overflowY

  var contentOverflows = rootElem.scrollHeight > rootElem.clientHeight
  var overflowShown    = /^(visible|auto)$/.test(overflowStyle) || /^(visible|auto)$/.test(overflowYStyle)
  var alwaysShowScroll = overflowStyle === 'scroll' || overflowYStyle === 'scroll'

  return (contentOverflows && overflowShown) || (alwaysShowScroll)
}
```

Comment: Not working in IE 11. window.innerWidth & document.documentElement.clientWidth are always same.

Comment: Fixed it. This same function works for IE 11 too. The issue was this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that

Comment: I tested this in Chrome 65 and it works. But when I adapt it for horizontal scrollbars, the result is strange: If both horizontal and vertical scrollbar are displayed, `window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth` is true, but `window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight` is not. It looks as if it were the other way around in this case. I am not a JS developer, I just need it for Selenium tests. I am grateful for hints.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
function windowHasScroll()
{
    return document.body.clientHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: this works fine but if you add height to body `height: 100%` then this will NOT work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply compare the width of the documents root element (i.e. html element) against the inner portion of the window:

```
if ((window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth) >0) console.log('V-scrollbar active')
```

If you also need to know the scrollbar width:

```
vScrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Comment: this is a clever solution and handles a edge case where html element has `overflow-y: scroll` but there is no actual overflow on the page. other solutions that check the height for overflow fails this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions didn't work in one of my projects and I've ending up checking overflow css property

```
function haveScrollbar() {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
    return style["overflow-y"] != "hidden";
}
```

but it will only work if scrollbar appear disappear by changing the prop it will not work if the content is equal or smaller than the window.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an updated version of Kees C. Bakker's answer:

```
const hasVerticalScroll = (node) => {
  if (!node) {
    if (window.innerHeight) {
      return document.body.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight
    }
    return (document.documentElement.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
      || (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight)
  }
  return node.scrollHeight > node.offsetHeight
}

if (hasVerticalScroll(document.querySelector('body'))) {
  this.props.handleDisableDownScrollerButton()
}
```

The function returns true or false depending whether the page has a vertical scrollbar or not.

For example:

```
const hasVScroll = hasVerticalScroll(document.querySelector('body'))

if (hasVScroll) {
  console.log('HAS SCROLL', hasVScroll)
}
```

Comment: this does not work if you explicitly set `overflow-y: scroll` on html tag and the page does not contain overflow. in this case, the vertical scrollbar will be visible (even though there is no overflow) and `hasVerticalScroll(document.querySelector('body'))` would incorrectly return `false`. @Babak's solution will handle this case.