# Detect when window vertical scrollbar appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, scrollbar

Is there a simple and reliable solution for detecting window vertical scrollbar appears/disappears?

`window.onresize` isn't triggered when after JavaScript DOM manipulation page becomes high enough for appearing scrollbar.

In this very similar post [Detect if a page has a vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar) described solution how to detect whether scrollbar is present or not, but I need to know when exactly it appears.

Answer (score 42):

Sorry to bring this back from the dead but I have just run in to this limitation and came up with my own solution. It's a bit hacky but stick with me ...

The idea is to add a 100% width invisible iframe to the page and listen for resize events on it's internal window. These events will pick up changes not only to the outer window's size but also when scrollbars get added to or removed from the outer window.

It triggers a regular window resize event so it requires no extra code if you are already listening for window resize.

Tested in IE9 and Chrome/Firefox latest - could maybe be made to work in older IEs but my project doesn't support those so I haven't tried.

https://gist.github.com/OrganicPanda/8222636

Comment: For anyone working in React, I've adapted this to a React component https://gist.github.com/AdamMcCormick/d5f718d2e9569acdf7def25e8266bb2a

Comment: Adapted as a React hook https://gist.github.com/curran/0e30c621fe4fc612bf7feb0938a68e4d

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it sounds like this would NOT work on a Mac, since their scrollbars do not take away from the width of the viewport.

Comment: The scrollbars on Mac/iOS do not take up space when they appear they only overlay the page when scrolling so there's no "resize" to worry about. For that reason this trick would still work for the intended use case of "know when the size of the document changes because of a vertical scrollbar". If your use case is more like "know when this element overflows the viewport and causes scrolling" this will not work. Both use cases are better served by `IntersectionObserver`/`ResizeObserver` these days but this answer was cool in 2014

Answer (score 8):

Based on OrganicPanda's answer, came up with this jquery thing

```
$('<iframe id="scrollbar-listener"/>').css({
    'position'      : 'fixed',
'width'         : '100%',
'height'        : 0, 
'bottom'        : 0,
'border'        : 0,
'background-color'  : 'transparent'
}).on('load',function() {
    var vsb     = (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight);
    var timer   = null;
    this.contentWindow.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            var vsbnew = (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight);
            if (vsbnew) {
                if (!vsb) {
                    $(top.window).trigger('scrollbar',[true]);
                    vsb=true;
                }
            } else {
                if (vsb) {
                    $(top.window).trigger('scrollbar',[false]);
                    vsb=false;
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}).appendTo('body');
```

This will trigger 'scrollbar' events on the window, if they appear/dissapear

Works on chrome/mac, at least. now, someone extend this to detect horizontal scrollbars :-)

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE7 or IE8 (I haven't tried in 9-11), but I guess that isn't too much of a concern for most people...

Answer (score 6):

#### The Scoop

It is possible to detect changes in scrollbar visibility by using `ResizeObserver` to check for changes in the size of the element that may take scrollbars and changes in the size of its contents.

#### Rationale

I started implementing a solution with the `<iframe>` method but quickly found that having a complete implementation required breaking the separation of concerns among the views of my application. I have a parent view which needs to know when a child view acquires a vertical scrollbar. (I don't care about the horizontal scrollbar.) I have two situations that may affect the visibility of the vertical scrollbar:

1. The parent view is resized. This is under direct control of the user.
2. The child view's contents becomes bigger or smaller. This is under indirect control of the user. The child view is showing the results of a search. The quantity and type of results determine the size of the child view.

I found that if I used `<iframe>` I'd have to muck with the child view to support the parent's needs. I prefer the child to not contain code for something which is purely a concern of the parent. With the solution I describe here, only the parent view needed to be modified.

So in looking for a better solution, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312522/1906307) by Daniel Herr. He suggests using `ResizeObserver` to detect when a div's dimensions change. `ResizeObserver` is not *yet* available natively across browsers but there is a robust ponyfill/polyfill that I use for support in cases where native support is not available. (Here is the [spec](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver) for `ResizeObserver`.)

#### Proof-of-Concept

I use [this polyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill) in its ponyfill mode. That way, the global environment remains untouched. This implementation relies on `window.requestAnimationFrame`, and will fall back on `setTimeout` for platforms that don't support `window.requestAnimationFrame`. Looking at the [support for `requestAnimationFrame`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe) on "Can I use...?", what I see there does not bother me. YMMV.

I have a live [proof-of-concept](https://plnkr.co/edit/8NcI4DWxgPpFSd6HT2v9?p=preview). The key is to listen to changes in size on the DOM element that can accept scroll bars (the element with id `container`, in green) and listen to changes in size on the content that may need scrolling (the element with id `content`). The proof-of-concept uses `interact.js` to manage a resizer element (with id `resizer`, in blue) that allows resizing `container`. If you drag the bottom right corner of `resizer`, it will resize both `resizer` and `container`. The two buttons allow simulating changes in the size of the contents displayed by `container`.

I'm using this method in code that is currently at a pre-release stage, meaning it passed tests on multiple browsers, and is being evaluated by stakeholders, but is not *yet* in production.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="interact.js@*" data-semver="1.0.26" src="//rawgit.com/taye/interact.js/v1.0.26/interact.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/master/dist/ResizeObserver.global.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resizer">
    <div id="container">
      <ul id="content">
        <li>Something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="add">Add to content</button>
  <button id="remove">Remove from content</button>
  <p>Scroll bar is: <span id="visibility"></span></p>
  <ul id="event-log"></ul>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var resizer = document.getElementById("resizer");
interact(resizer)
  .resizable({
    restrict: {
      restriction: {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: window.innerWidth - 10,
        bottom: window.innerHeight - 10
      }
    }
  })
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {
    var target = resizer;

    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    var width = rect.width + event.dx;
    var height = rect.height + event.dy;
    target.style.width = width + 'px';
    target.style.height = height + 'px';
  });

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>Foo</li>");
});

var remove = document.getElementById("remove");
remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
});

// Here is the code that pertains to the scrollbar visibility

var log = document.getElementById("event-log");
content.addEventListener("scrollbar", function () {
  log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>Scrollbar changed!</li>");
});

var visiblity = document.getElementById("visibility");
var previouslyVisible;
function refreshVisibility() {
  var visible = container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight;
  visibility.textContent = visible ? "visible" : "not visible";
  if (visible !== previouslyVisible) {
    content.dispatchEvent(new Event("scrollbar"));
  }
  previouslyVisible = visible;
}
// refreshVisibility();


var ro = new ResizeObserver(refreshVisibility);
ro.observe(container);
ro.observe(content);
```

The CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

#resizer {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using AngularJS, you can use a directive to detect when the width changes (assuming the appearing/disappearing scrollbar is a vertical one):

```
app.directive('verticalScroll', function($rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return element[0].clientWidth;
                },
                function() {
                    $rootScope.$emit('resize');
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

This fires an event on the root scope which other directives or controllers can listen for.

The watch is fired by the angular digest loop, so this relies on Angular having loaded/removed the extra content which has caused your scrollbar to appear/disappear.

Comment: can you please give an example how another directive would call this verticalScroll. @Dan

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically Detect Browser Vertical Scrollbar Event by
comparing window.innerWidth to getBoundingClientRect()
of a DIV element using Javascript. Tested with latest
IE FF Chrome. See documentation [here](http://www.websaber.com/detectVertBrowserScrollbar.htm)

Comment: I think the OP wanted an event that could be handled - detecting scrollbars can be easily done with faster methods (?).

Comment: Problems with this answer. First, the link has gone bad. Secondly, as the previous commenter pointed out, the issue the OP wants to solve is not just how to *detect* that there is a scrollbar but how to *get an event* notifying the code that a scrollbar has *become* visible or *become* hidden. Third, the way this answer is written, it is really hard to make out what it is supposed to say.

Comment: You mean window.innerHeight?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about *when* you need to determine the scrollbar's visibility.

The OP speaks of a time "after JavaScript DOM manipulation". If that manipulation happens in your code, then that's the time for checking if the scrollbar is visible. Why do you need an event in addition to that? How is it that you don't know when this DOM manipulation occurs?

I realize this is an old question, but I'm just now dealing with this in a pure javascript project, and I have no issue knowing when to check for scrollbar visibility.  Either a user event fires, or a system event fires, and I know when the DOM manipulation occurs because I'm causing it via javascript.  I don't see a case where that javascript DOM manipulation is outside of my code's awareness.

Maybe a scrollbarVisibilityChange event would be convenient, but it's certainly not necessary.  This strikes me as a non-issue, 9 years later.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to detect the scroll appearance on **Windows browsers** (except IE), here's my solution with **Resize Observer API** for vertical scroll as an example.

#### Idea

- Append `<div>` with `position: fixed` to `<body>`
- Make it **100% width** and **observe** for size changes
- The appearance of the scroll **reduces** the `<div>`'s **width**, which in turn calls the **observer callback**.

#### Why only Windows browsers?

Mobile and macOS browsers have a disappearing scroll that is taken out of the document flow and doesn't affect the page layout.

#### Why should the position be `fixed` and not `absolute`?

Element with `position: fixed` is positioned relative to the initial containing block **established by the viewport**.

`position: absolute` may fail if the `<body>` is also absolutely positioned and has a different width than the viewport.

```js
const innerWidthFiller = document.createElement('div')
innerWidthFiller.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0'
document.body.appendChild(innerWidthFiller)

const detectScroll = () => {
  const {clientHeight, scrollHeight} = document.documentElement
  window.result.value = scrollHeight > clientHeight
}

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(detectScroll)
resizeObserver.observe(innerWidthFiller)
```

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

output {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test.style.fontSize='100vh'">Enlarge the text</button>
<button onclick="test.style.fontSize=''">Reset</button>
Page scroll state: <output id="result"></output>

<hr>

<span id="test">Test element</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the ResizeObserver API solutions and some solution for detecting if a scrollbar exists or not, I came up with the following:

```js
// Create the ResizeObserver.
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    console.log('A vertical scrollbar appeared!');
    // Your code to deal with a vertical scrollbar...
  }
  
  if (document.body.scrollWidth > document.body.clientWidth) {
    console.log('A horizontal scrollbar appeared!');
    // Your code to deal with a horizontal scrollbar...
  }
});

// Observe the document body, or any HTML element whose size you expect to change when a scrollbar might appear.
resizeObserver.observe(document.body);

// Not part of the solution, but some code to illustrate the result:
const content = document.getElementById('content');

// Set some large text after 2 seconds to see the effect of a vertical scrollbar appearing.
setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
}, 2000);

// After 2 more seconds, make sure the text does not wrap to see the effect of a horizontal scrollbar appearing.
setTimeout(() => content.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap', 4000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p id="content"></p>
```