# How can I check if a scrollbar is visible or not?

Tags: javascript

I want to display a "Go to top"-Link on my website.
This link should only be visible, if the vertical scrollbar is visible.

How can I do this using JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175992/detect-when-window-vertical-scrollbar-appears

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a page has a vertical scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check `elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight` value but it also depends of css properties