# How do I find out whether the browser window has a scrollbar visible, in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there is a way of finding out whether a browser window has a scrollbar visible, in JQuery?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var hContent = $("body").height(); 
var hWindow = $(window).height(); 

if(hContent>hWindow) {
    $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(250);    
}
else {
    $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(250);
}
```

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the code then? isn't it working for you?

Comment: @niksvp - I need to somehow implement live to this so it picks up when there isnt a scrollbar visible...any ideas? I cant really test it at the moment because the page height is always greater than the viewport on page load

Comment: your problem is not clear. is that you are not getting jQuery effect? fadeIn/Out?

Comment: @niksvp - OK let me simplify, if the browser window has a vertical scroll, show #scroll-top...else hide #scroll-top. Problem: I have elements on my page that I can toggle therefore adjusting the page height...how do I get #scroll-top to disappear if I collapse/toggle all elements on the page?

Comment: Check this url [Detect if a page has a vertical scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following function.

```
function checkScrollBar() {
    var hContent = $("body").height(); // get the height of your content
    var hWindow = $(window).height();  // get the height of the visitor's browser window

    // if the height of your content is bigger than the height of the 
    // browser window, we have a scroll bar
    if(hContent>hWindow) { 
        return true;    
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This might not work if elements in your document have a fixed or absolute position.

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you compare `(window).height()` to `(document).height()` if the document height is greater than the window height then a scrollbar should be visible but this also depends on your CSS settings and whether overflow is hidden or visible.

**EDIT**

You need to create a listener in order for the code to run at the right time. This should work when the browser window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var hContent = $("body").height(); 
    var hWindow = $(window).height(); 

    if(hContent>hWindow) {
        $('#scroll-top').fadeIn(250);    
    }
    else {
        $('#scroll-top').fadeOut(250);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matt - My document has a scroller but can be toggled so it is shortened in height...There is a element I want to show when the browser window has a scroller. Sorry I'm a novice at JavaScript/JQuery

Comment: Could you edit some of you code into your question to demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Matt...I have added the code I'm working with to the question. I hope it gives you some insight into what I'm trying to achieve, Thanks

Comment: I need the fading effects to take place when the page height is toggled...I'm thinking something to do with .live() function

Comment: @Matt - You're on the right track...I need the listener to execute when the document height is greater OR less than the browser viewport(live)...The tricky bit is that on my document I can toggle elements to change the document height :S

Comment: If you change "body" to document, does that work? It should calculate the height of the document every time it changes.