# Modify FireFox extension: If (scrollbar exists) var - 30 else var -14

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hello fellow code people :)

I am a frontend web developer and as such in need of constant knowledge of the actual viewport size in order to see where in responsive designing breakpoints start and end.
I know FF's own 'test window size' function, but came across a very handy extension: FireSizer.
 the extension has one itsy bitsy drawback: It gives back the window-size including FF's borders and scrollbar. I need the viewport-size though. So I need the extension hacked, but dont't know enough javaScript to do so. Maybe someone is willing to help em out here?

I would love the extension to actually look for the scrollbar, and subtract from the width
a) 14 if no scrollbar present or
b) 30 if scrollbar present

I found of what I think is the right place to alter the code:

```
//
// Update the status bar panel with the current window size
//
function FiresizerUpdateStatus() {
    var width  = window.outerWidth  + ''; // <- Think code needs to be edited here
    var height = window.outerHeight + '';
    document.getElementById("firesizer-statuspanel").label = width + 'x' + height;
}
```

Thanks for any effort!
AO

@Chen Asraf:
Well thank you very much. I didn't know there was an element to call the document-width. I changed the code to the following, and that did the trick (also when compared to FF's own 'Responsive Design View mode', which is spot on, its off by 2px - which i subtract from clientWidth.)

```
function FiresizerUpdateStatus() {
var width  = window.outerWidth  + ''; // changed this line to:
var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth-2 + '';
var height = window.outerHeight + '';
document.getElementById("firesizer-statuspanel").label = width + 'M' + height;
}
```

Thanks 
AO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if a page has a vertical scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

Seems like you can get the window's inner dimensions by using:

```
// My window is maximized; screen is 1366x768

alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
// ^ returns 1349 (17 missing pixels because of scrollbar)

alert(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
// ^ returns 643 (125 pixels missing because of start bar & Chrome toolbars)
```

You can then compare the following with whatever else you need (for example, compare client width with window width to find if the difference is big enough to be a scrollbar - just experiment with the sizes)