# How to check if vertical scrolbar exists on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To check if the page has a scrollbar I used:

```
<script>
if (document.body.scrollWidth > document.body.offsetWidth){alert('exist');}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I check if scrollbar exists on page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: And of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar

Comment: Does this answer help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: thanks for help, not see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `scrollHeight` of the document:

```
if($(document.body)[0].scrollHeight > $(window).height()){
    alert('vertical scroll exists.');
}
```

---

A simple test scenario:

css:

```
body{height:2000px;} // here body tag of the document is 2000px in height
```

so the js would be like this:

```
if($('body')[0].scrollHeight > $(window).height()){
    alert('vertical scroll exists.');
}
```

or

```
if($(document.body)[0].scrollHeight > $(window).height()){
    alert('vertical scroll exists.');
}
```

here `$('body')[0].scrollHeight` you need to select your document's body.

#### [Test Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bHK8D/)

---

`$(document.body)[0].scrollHeight` instead of it you can also use `$(document).height()`

#### Note:

`$(selector)[0].scrollHeight` **This selector is not supported** by lesser than `IE version 8.0`

Comment: Why did you use `$(document)[0].scrollHeight` instead of `$(document).height()`?