# If document can be scrolled vertically by 200px or more run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery or plain JavaScript I want to run a function on `document ready`, if the page has a vertical scrollbar and the amount by which the page can be scrolled is `200px` or larger.

Basically, I want to modify the code below so that it runs on `document ready`, not when the user actually scrolls.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146874/detect-if-a-page-has-a-vertical-scrollbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i would do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(($(document).height() - $(window).height()) > 200)
  {
     //Do something.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `trigger` the `scroll` for `window`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).trigger('scroll');
   //or $(window).scroll();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
     if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
       // do stuff
     }
});
```

Comment: This still triggers on scroll? Asker wanted to check if a user could scroll, not actually if he scrolls but on pageready

Comment: @randy OP is saying _I want to modify the code below so it runs on document ready, not when the user actually scrolls_ i.e. he does not want to wait for user to scroll is what I presume..